# Not able to access dashboard of subdomain

Tags: multisite, subdomains

Recently I moved from WP Engine to A2 hosting. My site was working fine but suddenly once my WP Engine account deleted my sites stop working like previous.

Even I'm not able to access the subdomain dashboard from the main admin panel. It's displaying the same domain and redirects me to the same dashboard.

Comment: Did you recreate the website subdomains on a new hosting?

Comment: A business acquaintance showed me a similar situation recently. We reviewed the situation for about an hour. Here are some of our findings

1. We found quite a lot of additions to the wp-config file. But replacing the wp-config file with a clean version did not solve all the problems. 

2. There don't seem to be any new tables (related to WP Engine) added to the database.

3. There aren't any plugins specifically for WP Engine added to the dashboard plugin list.

4. There are many PHP errors that indicate missing functions. Those functions didn't export.

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins you are absolutely right. I fixed it through all these stuff. Thanks